Laravel migration failing when changing primary key: 1068 Multiple primary key defined
I have a table workflows with an auto-incrementing primary key called 'click_id'. I would like to add a field 'id' at the beginning of the table and make that the auto incrementing primary key.
This is the migration that fails:
Schema::table('workflows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('click_id')->change();
    $table->dropPrimary('click_id');
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->first();
    $table->unique(['click_id','review_id']);
});

The error is

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table workflows add id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key first)

This suggests that the dropPrimary() command is not completing before laravel continues onto the next line of the migration.
The only workaround I've found to be sucessful is to split it into two separate chunks within the up() method.
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('workflows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('click_id')->change();
        $table->dropPrimary('click_id');
    });

    Schema::table('workflows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->first();
        $table->unique(['click_id','review_id']);
    });
}


public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('workflows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropUnique('workflows_click_id_review_id_unique');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->change();
        $table->dropPrimary('id');
        $table->dropColumn('id');
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `workflows` CHANGE `click_id` `click_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, add PRIMARY KEY (`click_id`)');
}

Why does it not work as expected when within a single closure?
System: Laravel 10, MariaDB 10.4.32

Update:
Created a discussion on Github laravel/framework - it is considered a bug, but would be a big breaking change to fix.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/50925

Starting with this migration:
Schema::table('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('click_id')->change();
    $table->dropPrimary('click_id');
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->first();
    $table->unique(['click_id']);
});

This is the output that you get when dd'ing inside the build method of the Blueprint class (here)
2024_04_04_133407_test_change_index array:4 [
  0 => "alter table `test` modify `click_id` bigint unsigned not null"
  1 => "alter table `test` add `id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key first"
  2 => "alter table `test` drop primary key"
  3 => "alter table `test` add unique `test_click_id_unique`(`click_id`)"
]

As you can see, this does NOT follow the order of our instructions! The dropping of the primary key and the index queries get pushed to the end of the array.
Further research is needed to understand why they made this choice.
If you keep following the instruction pointer, you end up here:
protected function addImpliedCommands(Connection $connection, Grammar $grammar)
{
    if (count($this->getAddedColumns()) > 0 && ! $this->creating()) {
        array_unshift($this->commands, $this->createCommand('add'));
    }

    if (count($this->getChangedColumns()) > 0 && ! $this->creating()) {
        array_unshift($this->commands, $this->createCommand('change'));
    }

    $this->addFluentIndexes();

    $this->addFluentCommands($connection, $grammar);
}

Even without over-analyzing each of these calls, it seems the laravel chooses a specific order when it compiles the list of queries to run. That makes it necessary to separate the changes into 2 Schema::table(...) calls.

That would explain it! I assumed that laravel would run it in the same order. Thanks for digging that out.
